# Why I can access the dir // in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I found this dir in my ubuntu server

```
momo@myubuntuserver:/$ cd /
momo@myubuntuserver:/$ pwd
/
momo@myubuntuserver:/$ cd //
momo@myubuntuserver://$ pwd
//
momo@myubuntuserver://$ cd ///
momo@myubuntuserver:/$ pwd
/
```

why this dir exists ? How does it work ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Bash FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ):

```
E10) Why does `cd //' leave $PWD as `//'?

POSIX.2, in its description of `cd', says that *three* or more leading
slashes may be replaced with a single slash when canonicalizing the
current working directory.

This is, I presume, for historical compatibility.  Certain versions of
Unix, and early network file systems, used paths of the form
//hostname/path to access `path' on server `hostname'.
```

Answer (score 5):

`//` is just `/` on Linux. As is `///`, and `///bin//////ls` is an alternative name for `/bin/ls`.

Type `/bin/pwd` to find out the *real* present working directory.

Comment: The interesting question is why don't the shell prompt and pwd normalise `//` like they normalise `///`?

Comment: @DanielFischer: because according to the POSIX standard, `//` at the start of a path *may* have a special meaning to the OS, and Bash seems to cater to this. Linux doesn't attach such meanings, though. (I think Cygwin and other "Unix-for-Windows" packages use this to denote UNC network paths, but the convention goes back to Apollo Domain/OS.)